# Adding wp_editor to custom WP widget

Tags: wordpress, editor, tinymce

I want to add WP editor with TinyMCE to my custom text widget, but it won't show TinyMCE buttons it just shows textarea.
 When I test my code on page.php it works perfectly - editor shows with all the buttons and metabox.
 Can You please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
**EDIT**
[Widgets screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/2x431V3F1D2m).
[Same code used in page.php screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/38240m372J0D)

The code I use :

```
$settings = array(
    'wpautop' => true,
    'media_buttons' =>  false,
    'textarea_name' => 'test-editor',
    'textarea_rows' => get_option('default_post_edit_rows', 10),
    'tabindex' => '',
    'editor_css' => '',
    'editor_class' => '',
    'teeny' => true,
    'dfw' => true,
    'tinymce' => array(
          'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,underline' 
    ),
    'quicktags' => false
);
wp_editor( 'Text in editor', 'test-editor', $settings );
```

Comment: any js-errors on your js-console?

Comment: There are no js errors.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to find another WYSIWYG editor. [Reading the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor#Notes), there are two issues with your code:

1. The `$editor_id`

   > can only be composed of lower-case letters. No underscores, no hyphens. Anything else will cause the WYSIWYG editor to malfunction.
2. And this one that prevents the editor from working in a meta box

   > Once instantiated, the WYSIWYG editor cannot be moved around in the DOM. What this means in practical terms, is that you cannot put it in meta-boxes that can be dragged and placed elsewhere on the page.